# Apache Storm Nimbus Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I'm getting the following error trying so start storm nimbus for a local dev Windows 7 workstation:
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;C:\Program

storm.yaml:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
    - "127.0.0.1"

nimbus.seeds: ["127.0.0.1"]
storm.local.dir: "C:\\Users\\userX\\Apps\\ApacheStorm\\apache-storm-1.0.1\\data"
supervisor.slots.ports:
    - 6700
    - 6701
    - 6702
    - 6703
```

I successfully started ZooKeeper. But when I try to run: storm nimbus from the Storm bin folder I get the error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **PROGRA~1** instead of **Program files** in System variables' path.

For example: 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45 ==> C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_45`

Comment: Thanks goodspeed! That did it.Silly error, but it completely tripped me up until now.

Comment: I have tried this solution, but unfortunately this didn't worked for me. Can you please provide me some other solution.

Comment: @PraveenKishor try to check user variables, they might override system properties

Comment: I have already checked the user and system variables, and they seems okay.. is there any other solution for this ?