# Apache Storm Supervisor Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor

Tags: apache-storm

I'm getting the following error trying so start storm supervisor from Windows 7 workstation: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.

I was able to start nimbus successfully without any error.

P.S: Initially I had the same trouble with nimbus as well. Then I followed the solution given in [Apache Storm Nimbus Error: Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608271/apache-storm-nimbus-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like "Storm.cmd" withing the bin folder has the wrong class path for Supervisors.
In the cmd file the path is shown as:
CLASS=org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor

Whereas when comparing it to the python script the path is:
klass="org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Supervisor"

We updated storm.cmd to be the same as in the python and then it worked. 
Hope that helps